# Passing information between windows ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, html, button, postback

Here is the problem: I have a HTML page called test.html and an ASPX page called getitem.aspx.

Now what I want to do is, upon clicking a button on test.html, I want the getitem.aspx page to open in a new dialog and allow entry on a text box. After clicking the OK button on getitem.aspx, this dialog should close and the entry should be passed back to the html page.

The issue is that the getitem.aspx has several buttons that trigger postback - but I only want the item from the text box to be sent back to test.html upon clicking of the OK button and not any other buttons.

How could I implement this?

Comment: An HTML page is static - how are you passing data to it? How is it responding?

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript to do that 
first you need to use window.open() method to open the popup
after you have closed the page you should use window.opener for accessing to the closed windows and use javascript method like (getElementById) to find the element on that window and read it's value and then use !!

Hope it helps